# How could I restrict view access to message templates

Tags: permissions, message-templates

Wordpress. I know I can restrict edit access but I would like to restrict "use". So I can allow some users to send an email but not select a template. (otherwise they can use for instance CEO signature)

Comment: Not an answer to your question but if your concerns are mainly regarding the signatures you could have a look at this extension: https://docs.civicrm.org/signatures/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

I think its down to adding some code via php or js to restrict use of message template on some screen based on permission.